# MySQL function to convert UTC Time String to DATETIME

Tags: mysql

Is there any MYSQL function available to convert UTC Time String with TimeZone to DATETIME?

Ex: 2013-05-16T13:15:30Z

Cheers;

Comment: did you mean get the string into a timestamp? or also convert from zulu time to a specific timezone?

Comment: actually, I'm receiving time in UTC as a string. This is the format, 2013-05-16T13:15:30Z. Now I want to convert this and save it as a DATETIME in MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [convert_tz](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) directly on that timestamp:

```
select T,
  cast(T as datetime),  -- to cast 
  convert_tz(T, '+00:00', '+08:00')   -- to convert to local time
from 
  (select '2013-05-16T13:15:30Z' T) D
```

Depending upon your MySQL configuration you may be able to use `@@session.time_zone` to make the above `+08:00` less static

Comment: I want to convert this string, 2013-05-16T13:15:30Z into DATETIME using mysql function

Comment: so you want to keep it in zulu time?  both options are now in the answer